# Show cards before last player have decided

Tags: pre-flop, muck

Cashgame. Hold'em NL. Player A raise 40 preflop. Player B calls. Player C raises 240. Player A folds. Player C then throw his cards face up on the table and show pocket kings before player B have decided what to do. Player B has only 40 left in his stack. Deal say the hand is dead and give the entire pot to player B. Is this correct? Shouldn't player C atlease get 200 back? And forgo the 40 matching player B?

Answer (score 1):

Hand should never be dead. Player B should never be shipped the pot, especially the extra 200 that he couldn't cover. Whoever ruled the hand this way should be slapped.